# How to decode a JSON element?

Tags: r

I have this data acquired from a JSON routine, which includes 5 different records. Each record has either 41 or 0 sub-elements. In addition, sub-elements 40 and 41 are sub-lists.

I need to convert this into a main dataframe in which each record will show as a row with 39 columns (sub-lists can go away).
Also, records with no data (elements 2,3,4) will still show up as rows with NULL.

```
 a = list(structure(list(ConOrden = 1L, TipoMed = 1L, TipoPrest = 2L, 
                         CausaS1 = 0L, CausaS2 = 0L, CausaS3 = 0L, MedPBSUtilizado = NA, 
                         RznCausaS31 = 0L, DescRzn31 = NA, RznCausaS32 = 0L, DescRzn32 = NA, 
                         CausaS4 = 1L, MedPBSDescartado = NA, RznCausaS41 = 0L, DescRzn41 = NA, 
                         RznCausaS42 = 0L, DescRzn42 = NA, RznCausaS43 = 1L, DescRzn43 = "N.A.", 
                         RznCausaS44 = 0L, DescRzn44 = NA, CausaS5 = 1L, RznCausaS5 = NA, 
                         CausaS6 = NA, DescMedPrinAct = "[APIXABAN] 5mg/1U", CodFF = "COLFF001", 
                         CodVA = "048", JustNoPBS = "Paciente con infeccion por sarscov2", 
                         Dosis = "5", DosisUM = "0168", NoFAdmon = "12", CodFreAdmon = 2L, 
                         IndEsp = 10L, CanTrat = "3", DurTrat = 5L, CantTotalF = "180", 
                         UFCantTotal = "66", IndRec = "Paciente con infeccion por sarscov2", 
                         EstJM = 1L, PrincipiosActivos = list(structure(list(ConOrden = 1L, 
                                                                             CodPriAct = "08626", ConcCant = "5", UMedConc = "0168", 
                                                                             CantCont = "1", UMedCantCont = "0247"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
                         IndicacionesUNIRS = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
          list(), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
          structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
          structure(list(ConOrden = 1L, TipoMed = 1L, TipoPrest = 2L, 
                         CausaS1 = 0L, CausaS2 = 0L, CausaS3 = 0L, MedPBSUtilizado = NA, 
                         RznCausaS31 = 0L, DescRzn31 = NA, RznCausaS32 = 0L, DescRzn32 = NA, 
                         CausaS4 = 1L, MedPBSDescartado = "OXICODONA", RznCausaS41 = 1L, 
                         DescRzn41 = "extreñimiento", RznCausaS42 = 0L, DescRzn42 = NA, 
                         RznCausaS43 = 0L, DescRzn43 = NA, RznCausaS44 = 0L, DescRzn44 = NA, 
                         CausaS5 = 1L, RznCausaS5 = NA, CausaS6 = NA, DescMedPrinAct = "[ACETAMINOFEN] ", 
                         CodFF = "COLFF001", CodVA = "048", JustNoPBS = "dolor de dificil modulacion", 
                         Dosis = "325", DosisUM = "0168", NoFAdmon = "8", CodFreAdmon = 2L, 
                         IndEsp = 10L, CanTrat = "60", DurTrat = 3L, CantTotalF = "180", 
                         UFCantTotal = "66", IndRec = "tomar una cada 8 horas ", 
                         EstJM = 1L, PrincipiosActivos = list(structure(list(ConOrden = c(1L, 
                                                                                          1L), CodPriAct = c("00626", "50055"), ConcCant = c("325", 
                                                                                                                                             "30"), UMedConc = c("0168", "0168"), CantCont = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "1"), UMedCantCont = c("0247", "0247")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
                         IndicacionesUNIRS = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each list elements return first 39 columns if number of rows in the data is greater than 0. If the element is empty return an empty tibble with a single column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

result <- map_df(a, ~if(NROW(.x) > 0) .x %>% select(1:39) 
                      else tibble(ConOrden = NA), .id = 'id')
dim(result)

#[1]  5 40
```

In the output we have 40 columns because the first column `id` is used to uniquely identify all the list element. For this example, `id` 2, 3 and 4 will have all columns as `NA`.